# awk - compare 2 files and print columns from both files

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, awk

I posted something similar a while ago and I thought, the code provided could help in solving my problem, however unfortunately I am not able to adjust it to my needs: [awk - compare files and print lines from both files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884340/awk-compare-files-and-print-lines-from-both-files)

So, I have again 2 tab-separated files.

file_1.txt

```
apple    2.5    5     7.2
great    3.8    10    3.6
see      7.6    3     4.9
tree     5.4    11    5
back     8.9    2     2.1
```

file_2.txt

```
apple    :::N
back     :::ADJ
back     :::N      
around   :::ADV      
great    :::ADJ         
bee      :::N         
see      :::V      
tree     :::N
```

The output should look like:

```
apple    :::N      2.5    5     7.2     
great    :::ADJ    3.8    10    3.6
back     :::ADJ    8.9    2     2.1
back     :::N      8.9    2     2.1
see      :::V      7.6    3     4.9
tree     :::N      5.4    11    5
```

The difference to the other post is, that I just like to compare the first columns of file_1.txt and file_2.txt and then print the whole line of file_1.txt with column 2 of file_1.txt to the outfile. I do not care in which order $2 of file_2.txt is printed to the outfile, so the outfile could as well look like

```
back     8.9    2     2.1    :::N
back     8.9    2     2.1    :::V etc.
```

The problem are the duplicates in column1 as back here. Otherwise I could of course just use `paste`. 
The problem with this `awk-command is, that it does not read column2 in the a array and if I tell it to print it, this is not possible of course.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a {print $0, a[$2]}' OFS='\t' file_2.txt file_1.txt > outfile.txt
```

I am gladly appreciating any help! Sorry for the stupidity here also, seems that I am completely stumped.

Comment: How can we know which of the two `back` values from `file2` correspond to each of the two `back` values in `file1`?

Comment: If order is not important, you could consider using `join` instead e.g. `join -t $'\t' <(sort file_1.txt) <(sort file_2.txt)`

Comment: @terdon thank you, this is a really good question. I like to add the values for _back_ regardless of $2 of `file_1.txt`. So, they should basically be treated as 2 different lines even though containing the same word. In the end it would just be important that both lines are considered, so that in the output file, there is one line with `back` as `:::V` and another with `:::N`

Comment: @steeldriver nice, it is great, you are always solving my problems, thank you so much! can I accept your code somewhere in the comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have GNU `awk` (available from the repository via package `gawk`), which supports multi-dimensional arrays, you could do

```
gawk 'NR==FNR {a[$1][$2]++; next} $1 in a {for (x in a[$1]) print $0, x}' OFS="\t" file_2.txt file_1.txt
```

Ex.

```
$ gawk 'NR==FNR {a[$1][$2]++; next} $1 in a {for (x in a[$1]) print $0, x}' OFS="\t" file_2.txt file_1.txt
apple   2.5     5       7.2     :::N
great   3.8     10      3.6     :::ADJ
see     7.6     3       4.9     :::V
tree    5.4     11      5       :::N
back    8.9     2       2.1     :::ADJ
back    8.9     2       2.1     :::N
```

Otherwise, if output order is not important the easiest solution is probably to use the `join` command instead:

```
$ join -t $'\t' <(sort file_1.txt) <(sort file_2.txt)
apple   2.5     5       7.2     :::N
back    8.9     2       2.1     :::ADJ
back    8.9     2       2.1     :::N
great   3.8     10      3.6     :::ADJ
see     7.6     3       4.9     :::V
tree    5.4     11      5       :::N
```