# How to compare and replace the value at particular location with awk

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, csv

I want to compare two `csv` files with one common column and then replace the data from first file to second file at particular location.

file1.csv:

```
"id","name","marks","subject","result"
"1","a","","art",""
"4","c","","math",""
"3","b","","history",""
"5","d","","comerce",""
```

file2.csv:

```
"id","marks","result"
"4","40","pass"
"3","30","fail"
"1","20","fail"
"6","10",""
"5","10",""
```

output should be:

```
"id","name","marks","subject","result"
"1","a","20","art","fail"
"4","c","40","math","pass"
"3","b","30","history","fail"
"5","d","10","comerce",""
```

I am using the `awk` statement as below but it merging the value at last not adding at particular location:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; b[$1]=$3; next}  {print $0, a[$2], b[$2] } file1.csv file2.csv
```

Comment: "it merging the value at last" doesn't make sense to me, perhaps an example wrong output to save people time. Also, it's "commerce" FWIW. This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/890557/awk-compare-2-files-and-print-columns-from-both-files?rq=1) seems very similar, and the suggestion to use `join` [then awk, perhaps] seems a good one, especially if you have a common key.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS=","} 
  NR==FNR {
    marks[$1]=$2; status[$1]=$3; next
  } 
  $1 in marks {$3 = marks[$1]} 
  $1 in status {$5 = status[$1]}
  1' file2.csv file1.csv
"id","name","marks","subject","result"
"1","a","20","art","fail"
"4","c","40","math","pass"
"3","b","30","history","fail"
"5","d","10","comerce",""
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer. Will it work for more number of columns say 45 ?

Comment: @user828007  I can't answer that - whether it "works" will depend on what you want to happen to the additional columns